# Rename object keys in cartesian output

Tags: javascript, cartesian-product

Sorry for the bad question title, couldn't figure a better one.

I have this array of options:

```
const options = [
  {
    display_name: "Size",
    _id: "1",
    values: [
      {
        label: "Small",
        _id: "1"
      },
      {
        label: "Extra Large",
        _id: "2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    display_name: "Colors",
    _id: "2",
    values: [
      {
        label: "Red",
        value: "#ff0000",
        _id: "3"
      },
      {
        label: "Green",
        value: "#00ff21",
        _id: "4"
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

I run this function against it to get `Cartesian Product`:

```
const getCartesian = object => {
  return Object.entries(object).reduce(
    (r, [key, value]) => {
      let temp = [];
      r.forEach(s =>
        (Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value]).forEach(w =>
          (w && typeof w === "object" ? getCartesian(w) : [w]).forEach(x =>
            temp.push(Object.assign({}, s, { [key]: x }))
          )
        )
      );
      return temp;
    },
    [{}]
  );
};
```

This will result in an array of objects in the following format (console.log output):

```
[{0: Object, 1: Object}, {0: Object, 1: Object}, ...]
```

The desired output is:

```
[
            {
               "option":{
                  "id":1,
                  "display_name":"Size"
               },
               "value":{
                  "label":"Small",
                  "id": 1
               }
            },
            {
               "option":{
                  "id":2,
                  "display_name":"Color",
               },
               "value":{
                  "id":5,
                  "label":"Red"
               }
            }
...
]
```

here's the playground and what I've tried so far: https://codesandbox.io/s/8nvwm76nnj

Comment: sure, I'll update the question in a moment

Comment: itr's not sure your output.. do you want a new object for each value in values array or do you want to use just first element value[0]?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `map()` at the end to convert array to object.

```js
const options = [
  {
    display_name: "Size",
    _id: "1",
    values: [
      {
        label: "Small",
        _id: "1"
      },
      {
        label: "Extra Large",
        _id: "2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    display_name: "Colors",
    _id: "2",
    values: [
      {
        label: "Red",
        value: "#ff0000",
        _id: "3"
      },
      {
        label: "Green",
        value: "#00ff21",
        _id: "4"
      },
    ]
  }
];

const getCartesian = object => {
      let t = Object.entries(object).reduce(
        (r, [key, value]) => {
          let temp = [];
          r.forEach(s =>
            (Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value]).forEach(w =>
              (w && typeof w === "object" ? getCartesian(w) : [w]).forEach(x =>
                temp.push(Object.assign({}, s, { [key]: x }))
              )
            )
          );
          return temp;
        },
        [{}]
      );
      return t.map(({0:val1,1:val2}) => ({option:val1,arr:val2}))
    };
console.log(getCartesian(options));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think that the `getCartesian` is not providing the desired result at all (not yours, even the original one). I can't get it to match the desired output, now it results to: `option:{
display_name: "Size"
_id: "1"},
values: {
label: "Small"
_id: "1"},
value:{
display_name: "Colors"
_id: "2"},
values: {
label: "Red"
value: "#ff0000"
_id: "5"}`

Comment: @Stathis Ntonas Please add complete expected output instead of `...`

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the array in an object with a property `option`. This gives you later an array with objects with `option` as key for the cartesian product.

```js
const getCartesian = object => {
    return Object.entries(object).reduce(
        (r, [key, value]) => {
            let temp = [];
            r.forEach(s =>
                (Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value]).forEach(w =>
                    (w && typeof w === "object" ? getCartesian(w) : [w]).forEach(x =>
                        temp.push(Object.assign({}, s, { [key]: x }))
                    )
                )
            );
            return temp;
        },
        [{}]
    );
};
const options = [{ display_name: "Size", _id: "1", values: [{ label: "Small", _id: "1" }, { label: "Extra Large", _id: "2" }] }, { display_name: "Colors", _id: "2", values: [{ label: "Red", value: "#ff0000", _id: "3" }, { label: "Green", value: "#00ff21", _id: "4" }] }];

console.log(getCartesian({ option: options }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```